# <div> tags inside <div> using importXML Xpath query, in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: html, google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I'm using Xpath in Google docs to get the text inside `<div>`.
I want to save the text inside `<div id="job_description">` in one cell of Google doc spreadsheet, but it shows each `<div>` in separate cell.

```
<div id="job_description">
    <div>
        <strong>
            Basic Purpose:
        </strong>
        <br></br>
    </div>
    <div>
        Work closely with developers, product owners and Q…
        <br></br>
    </div>
    <div>
        The Test Analyst is accountable for the developmen…
        <br></br>
    </div>
    <div>
        <strong>
            Duties and Responsibilities:
        </strong>
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
    <div>
        <strong>
            Requirements:
        </strong>
        <br></br>
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Image:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0mAY.png

and this is the code I wrote:

```
=IMPORTXML(E4,"//div[@id='job_description']")
```

May you help me to put all of the text (including `<div>` `<ul>` ...)  inside the `<div id="job_description">` in only one cell ?

Comment: And what is in cell E4? A URL to a page? Do you only want the _text_ content?

Comment: Yes, E4 is URL . I want all the texts that are inside div and ul to be in one cell .
As I show in the image, currently each div is in separate cell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using JOIN is a good start, but you can make it a single operation.

You did not show the URL to the page you're importing, so I can only give you an example with another page. For instance, if you are importing www.w3.org and looking for a `div` where `@class='event closed expand_block'`, use

```
=JOIN(CHAR(10),IMPORTXML("http://www.w3.org/","//div[@class='event closed expand_block']//text()"))
```

Notice that I also modified the XPath expression: `//text()` makes sure only descendant text nodes are retrieved, that is, all the text.

---

**EDIT**: Responding to your comment:

> May I know what is CHAR(10) referring to?

Yes, of course. `CHAR` returns a character and takes a number as input. In the case of `CHAR(10)`, a *newline* character is returned (I assume because of `&#10;`).

In the formula, `CHAR(10)` is used as the first argument of `JOIN`, which is the *delimiter* of the objects that are to be joined.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know you want the URL.. I tried it and it perfectly works . this is URL : http://jobs.jobstreet.com/sg/jobs/4442635?fr=J&src=27
</br> and this is code: 
=JOIN(CHAR(10),IMPORTXML(E5,"//div[@id='job_description']//text()"))
May I know what is CHAR(10)  referring to?

Comment: Thanks for help, The XPath you gave me, returned the results exactly as I wanted

Answer (score 1):

For now I found a solution , I'll put it here so that others can know my answer, but if there is any other solution please let us know

I used `JOIN` to put the separate cells `(L3:X3)` into one single cell

```
=Trim(JOIN(" ",L3:X3))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use regexreplace to remove the line breaks, with

```
=REGEXREPLACE(IMPORTXML(E4,"//div[@id='job_description']"),"\n","")
```

this should wrap it all into one cell for you.