# Import data into Google Sheets using IMPORTXML with the div-class

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I did some research and found a *div-class* example of [*importXML*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28265221/div-tags-inside-div-using-importxml-xpath-query-in-google-spreadsheet) for Google Sheets (see first sample code below), however it doesn't appear to be working in this instance with a BBC website in Arabic. Does anyone have insight on how to solve this?

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.w3.org/","//div[@class='event closed expand_block']//text()")

=IMPORTXML("http://www.bbc.com/arabic/middleeast","//div[@class='top-stories__stories']//text()")
```

Bonus points if anyone can figure how to group the data from individual news stories using JOIN.

Comment: I encountered this issue too. It seems that even the queries in the [official docs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en) give rise to errors ("The xPath query did not return any data.")

Answer (score -2):

//*[@id="comp-recent-media"]/div/div[1]